React Native Warning: A props object containing a "key" prop is being spread into JSX with BottomTab.Navigator and react-native-paper
I'm encountering the following warning in my React Native project when using BottomTab.Navigator from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs and BottomNavigation.Bar from react-native-paper
Error
Warning: A props object containing a "key" prop is being spread into JSX: 
<Touchable {...props} />
React keys must be passed directly to JSX without using spread.

Here’s a code snippet of how I have set up my bottom tab navigation:
function AppNav({ routes }) {
  const renderTabBar = ({ navigation, state, descriptors, insets }) => {
    const navigationBarProps = {
      version: 3,
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "#212529",
      },
      activeColor: "orange",
      inactiveColor: "lightgrey",
      shifting: false,
      navigationState: state,
      safeAreaInsets: insets,
      onTabPress: ({ route, preventDefault }) => {
        const event = navigation.emit({
          type: "tabPress",
          target: route.key,
          canPreventDefault: true,
        });

        if (event.defaultPrevented) {
          preventDefault();
        } else {
          navigation.dispatch({
            ...CommonActions.navigate(route.name, route.params),
            target: state.key,
          });
        }
      },
      renderIcon: ({ route, focused }) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
        return options.tabBarIcon ? options.tabBarIcon({ focused, size: 24 }) : null;
      },
      getLabelText: ({ route }) => {
        const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
        return options.tabBarLabel ?? route.name;
      },
    };

    return <BottomNavigation.Bar {...navigationBarProps} />;
  };

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      tabBar={renderTabBar}
    >
      {routes?.map((route) => (
        <BottomTab.Screen
          key={route.key}
          name={route.name}
          component={route.component}
          options={{
            title: route.name,
            tabBarIcon: ({ size, focused }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name={focused ? route.icon_focused : route.icon_default}
                color={focused ? "orange" : "#fafafa"}
                size={size}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}

This happened when i upgraded my dependencies. Here are my current package versions:
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.1",
    "expo": "^52.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.19",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.14",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.16",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.25",



The warning stems from react-native-paper's BottomNavigation.Bar component. For the renderTouchable prop, there's a default value with a spread syntax like the below
...
renderTouchable = (props: TouchableProps<Route>) => <Touchable {...props} />,
...

To fix this, pass your own Touchable where key is separated from the rest of the props like,
renderTouchable={({key, ...props}) => (<TouchableRipple key={key} {...props} />)}


This solved the issue!

Yes, that warning appears due to changes in React 18.
You now have to pass key as a separate argument.
Example
const { key, ...rest } = props;

<SomeComponent key={key} {...rest} />


I understand that the warning is related to how React 18 handles the key prop, and I have seen the suggestion to separate the key prop when spreading props. However, I’m not explicitly spreading the key prop anywhere in my code. I am using BottomTab.Screen, where I pass the key directly as an attribute.

You don't have to pass the key along the spreaded props. You can still spread the object containing your props as long as it doesn't have the key prop. If you want to pass the key prop, do it separetly.

Find BottomNavigationBar.tsx in

node_modules/react-native-paper/src/components/BottomNavigation/BottomNavigationBar.tsx

Inside the file, change
renderTouchable = (props: TouchableProps<Route>) => <Touchable {...props} />,

to
renderTouchable = ({key, ...props}: TouchableProps<Route> & { key: string }) => (
  <TouchableRipple key={key} {...props} />
),

And that should be it.
This is an homemade recipe.

My issue was related to the react-native-tab-view and I only updated my package version and it worked for me.

Before the warning

: "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1"

After warning

"react-native-tab-view": "^4.0.5"
